# How to fetch xml element inside a xml

Tags: java, xml

Hi I want to fetch whole `<request> </request>` ie the small part of xml as it is `<com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>
          <billingPk>
            <lsBanPk>
              <lsBan>17957</lsBan>
              <divisionId>PZA</divisionId>
              <systemId>OPWQ</systemId>
            </lsBanPk>
            <btnPk>
              <btn>6184</btn>
              <custCode>1</custCode>
              <divisionId>ILEPOR</divisionId>
              <systemId>ACSQQWE</systemId>
            </btnPk>
            <attProductType>UVERSE_STANDALONE</attProductType>
          </billingPk>
        </com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>` in this particular format only .I dont want to use File Reader and fetch its contents as a String.Can i do it in java using any of the XML parsers?

> XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <apis xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vdb-api-config.xsd">
        <api>
            <serviceName>Billing</serviceName>
            <methodName>getBilling</methodName>
            <request>
      <com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>
      <billingPk>
        <lsBanPk>
          <lsBan>17957</lsBan>
          <divisionId>PZA</divisionId>
          <systemId>OPWQ</systemId>
        </lsBanPk>
        <btnPk>
          <btn>6184</btn>
          <custCode>1</custCode>
          <divisionId>ILEPOR</divisionId>
          <systemId>ACSQQWE</systemId>
        </btnPk>
        <attProductType>UVERSE_STANDALONE</attProductType>
      </billingPk>
    </com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>
        </request>
        </api>
    </apis>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. (SCNR)

Comment: If you simply do not know how to parse XML with Java, then do a little research. There are hundreds of tutorials dealing with that topic. If you know how to parse XML but got stuck at a special point, then please post your code and your problematic location.

Comment: Use JAXB. You have an XML Schema. Compile it, using xjc. Compile using javac, write your application, unmarshal.

Comment: Your title is misleading. You don't want to fetch an **embedded** XML document, you just want to get an **element** from an XML document.

Comment: I Want to fetch whole **<request> </request>** ie '<com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>
      <billingPk>
        <lsBanPk>
          <lsBan>17957</lsBan>
          <divisionId>PZA</divisionId>
          <systemId>OPWQ</systemId>
        </lsBanPk>
        <btnPk>
          <btn>6184</btn>
          <custCode>1</custCode>
          <divisionId>ILEPOR</divisionId>
          <systemId>ACSQQWE</systemId>
        </btnPk>
        <attProductType>UVERSE_STANDALONE</attProductType>
      </billingPk>
    </com.shared.to.wireline.Billing>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it with [dom xml parser](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html).

```
File fXmlFile = new File("XmlFile.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("request");

for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++){
     Node node = nodes.item(i);
     if(node instanceof Element){
         // get node name and value
        System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + node.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("Node Value =" + node.getTextContent());

        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {

            // loop again if it has child nodes
           NodeList childNodes = tempNode.getChildNodes();

           //Iterate the nodes again perhaps using recursion. 

        }
     }
}
```

Read more at [Looping the Node](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath API.
XPath is a language for finding information in an XML file. You can say that XPath is (sort of) SQL for XML files. XPath is used to navigate through elements and attributes in an XML document. You can also use XPath to traverse through an XML file in Java.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to transform this xml into a java object and get this information (Unmarshalling process), then you can get wherever information you want.

Here is a very good and simple tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/